# Why is the "belle-sœur" Belle?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, société

Can anyone tell me why sister-in-law is "**BELLE**-sœur"? I am curious about the derivation of the term. Why is a sister-in-law a *good/beautiful* person?

Comment: This extends to the father/mother-in-law and the answer might also be interesting for stepfather/mother which have the same translation (_beau-père_ / _belle-mère_).

Comment: Because you don't want your wife (it might be her sister), your brother (it might be his wife) or your father (in the case of your step mother) to punch you. Everything else has been said.

Answer (score 9):

On parle de la première [attestation](https://books.google.com/books?id=KVdeYDenmcAC&dq=Revue%20Histoire%20litt%C3%A9rature%20fran%C3%A7aise%201423%20%22belle-soeur%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=bourgogne%20soeur) écrite de [*belle-sœur*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/belle-soeur) en français dans son sens *courant* (par alliance) en 1423, dans un traité entre [Frédéric d'Autriche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_IV_d'Autriche) et [Catherine de Bourgogne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_de_Bourgogne), l'épouse de son frère :

[image]

<sup>*Histoire générale et particulière de Bourgogne, avec des notes, des dissertations et les preuves justificatives.* - Dijon, de Fay 1739-81, t.3, CCXXVIII, p. CCXXIX</sup>

[*Bel*](http://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/beau) avait déjà été utilisé comme *épithète de courtoisie* (par exemple [*bel sire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GRnrAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3A4d6YCsVb2VEC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=bel%20sire) dans *la vie de saint Alexis*, au 11<sup>e</sup>) et c'est ainsi que le *TLFi* explique la composition dans *belle-sœur*. Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*) dit que c'était employé au 12<sup>e</sup> comme terme d'affection pour « chère soeur » ; avant d'employer belle-soeur pour la « soeur du mari » (1423, voir aussi *FEW* [soror](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/238036), [bellus](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/30176)), on avait *sororge/[serorge](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEM=SERORGE2;ISIS=isis_dmf2015.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;OO1=2;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=0;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;XXX=4;;)* au 13<sup>e</sup> pour désigner la même chose (entre [autres](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/120/118)). On peut noter que certains emplois anciens de l'élément belle *ou* sœur peuvent s'appliquer aux deux genres ou bénéficier d'extensions de sens ou d'usages particuliers, et il peut y avoir, selon le contexte, concurrence entre l'orthographe de *soror*/soeur par exemple, et des mots distincts basés sur les racines [*senior*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/235667) et [*socer*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/235668).

---

This was not about the beauty meaning but rather used originally as a *courtesy* (see *Larousse* [*5. dans des appellations*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/beau/8465)) akin to something like (*my*) ***dear/good*** sister. The contemporary meaning (sister-in-law) is attested by 1423.

Answer (score 6):

*Beau* and *belle* are originally coming from the Middle Ages. There were at this time specific terms to describe the son-in-law (*fillastre*), father-in-law (*parastre*), mother-in-law (*marastre*).  Similarly, for brother-in-law and sister-in-law, *serorge* was the analogous term. However, when you did like someone from your family, you were usually using the *biaus* and *bele* words (which became *beau* and *belle*) to refer to those people, for instance *bele suer* for the sister-in-law.

The original end of those words, *astre*, became pejorative. Since that time, it has been replaced with *beau* and *belle* to refer to those people, giving *beau-frère*, *beau-père*, ...

As the language evolved, *serorge* was also replaced, and led to *belle soeur*.

Source : [Langue-fr.net](http://www.langue-fr.net/Beaux-parents-emploi-de-beau)

Comment: A *fillastre* (*fillâtre*) was a son-in-law, not a sister-in-law. There is no evidence *suorastre / soeurâtre* ever existed. On the other hand, *sororge* was used for both brother and sister-in-law.

Comment: The following is meant as a bad joke and a gratuitous slam of my wonderful French mother-in-law, but I notice you left out the modern version of “marastre” in your closing sentence. Could that be because you sometimes call yours what I often call mine (belle-doche), which is probably no better than calling her “marastre”?  (Regardless, +1 !)

Comment: @jilliagre You're indeed right, my apologies. I've corrected my answer.
(Ah ah, good one Papa Poule).

Comment: Good to mention that despite its very pejorative connotation, `marâtre` can still be used to make the distinction between "the new wife of your father" and "the mother of your wife" , who both are your "belle-mère" if you don't use `marâtre`. It also seems that legally, and probably for the same reason, `parâtre` is used for "the new husband of your mother", but I hardly ever heard it myself.

Comment: @Isuka I am not sure what you mean by "when you did like someone from your family".  Do you mean that as comethapaxj'ajax said it was an endearment applied to a biological family member?

Comment: @Micromégas That's a point of my answer which is indeed important to clarify. In fact, _biaus_ and _bele_ were both used to describe any kind of person you appreciated, such as a member of your family, a good friend or someone you had respect for (as comet hapax d'ajax said in his answer). But it was mainly used between people of the same family. By this, I do not mean only the biological family, but the entire one.